# Почему description выводится некорректно?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, seo, meta

У клиента сайт на вордпресс с установленным плагином SEOPress. Через этот плагин выводятся title, description и прочие мета-теги. Проблема в том что description в поиске отображается некорректно (выводится левый текст, либо код со страницы). Хотя в самом теге описание соответствует тому которое было прописано. В google search console описание тоже верное, правда оно в формате JSON. Это вообще нормально? А еще смущает что описание страницы заполняется в поле с названием "Описание видео", текст в description при этом соответствует его содержимому. Так же описание страниц отличается в Яндексе и Google
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это нормально. Особенно если гадать без пациента.